# powershell上でのnpm：「内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド～」というこの謎の警告はなんなのか？

Tags: powershell, npm

コマンドライン（powershell）のnpmコマンドについて質問です。

**問題**

- 環境：　windows11
- CMD：　windows terminal powershell (vscodeでも同)

vscodeのターミナルやデフォルトのターミナルで`npm`コマンドを実行したとき、最初のログで「'+' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、 操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。」

この警告だけでも意味がわからないのですが、npmを実行したときの'+'というのがもっとわからないです。

**試したこと**

- 環境変数で実行パスを見直した
- PATHEXTに`.cmd`を追加、確認
- 「管理者権限で実行」を試した

Comment: 実行している`npm`コマンドというのはどういう素性のものですか?

Comment: 「環境変数で実行パスを見直した」とありますが、具体的にどのような操作を行ったのか質問中に記載しておくと回答のヒントになるかもしれません。

Comment: もしかしたらこんな記事 [npm installで作成した実行batファイルの中身がおかしい時](https://qiita.com/Fushihara/items/844a19470c3c2affc6b9) に書かれている内容(`\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\cmd-shim\index.js`ファイル関連)が何かしら上手く動いていないか悪影響が発生しているのかも？ 何か怪しいログが表示されたり内容のおかしなファイルが出来ていたりしませんか？

Comment: 単純に言えば、`+`で始まる行を持つ何かをコマンド/スクリプト/バッチファイル等として実行した、ということでしょう。`'+' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、 操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。`の文言はコマンドプロンプト(CMD.EXE)のコンソールで表示されるものなので、その何かをシェルコマンドとして実行したものと思われます。VSCodeやPowerShellのウインドウではなく、コマンドプロンプト上で単に`+`として実行してみれば同じ内容が表示されるでしょう。